# Editing a new list of vector3's without changing the original list? (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity

I just got Vectrosity for Unity and need to make a line of all the destinations for an object. Issue is that I need to use a single list of vector3's to create the line (as far as I'm aware).

I have a list of vector3's that is the objects queued destinations. I then need to insert the objects current location at index [0] in the list so that the first line point is at the objects location. Issue is that no matter how I try and accomplish this I'm still referencing the original destinations list, and inserting something at [0] on the list for the lines changes the original destinations list as well.

How do I go about creating a single List from a list of vector3's and an extra point without changing the original list that is being referenced? Do I need to clone it?

Comment: Maybe you can show us the code you've tried already and what you think the problem is with it. That'll make it much easier to answer this question and make the answer more relevant to you.

Comment: This is a general programming question, not specific to game development.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Vector3> newList = new List<Vector3>(originalList);
newList.Insert(0, currentLocation);
```

`originalList` in this example hasn't been modified and should have 1 less element than `newList`.

Another way:

```
List<Vector3> newList = new List<Vector3>();
newList.Add(currentLocation);
newList.AddRange(originalList);
```